# Chaos theory and population cycles of odd periodicity

Tags: ecology, mathematical-models, population-dynamics, theoretical-biology

I have just begun to read about Chaos theory and have come across the statement that "Period three implies chaos."

My question: Does any odd period imply chaos or only 3? If so, how can populations of cicadas that cycle every 17 years exist?

Comment: Can you give a bit more background? What period 3?

Comment: @chris Period 3 means a cycle of 3 years.

Comment: Ahh, now. Lifecycles based in the number 3 overlap with several others - 6, 9, 12, yearly, and so on. If the lifecycle is only 17 years, then a parasite needs to have exactly the same lifecycle (its a primer number so there are no other fractions) to meet its host.

Comment: @Chris Ummm..I have read that before and I am not trying to ask the reason why 17 year cycle are beneficial, i am asking how can they EXIST in the first place ?

Comment: @Chris It will become clearer to you what exactly am asking after reading [this](http://www.jcu.edu/math/vignettes/population.htm)

Comment: Oh. I will have a look into your resource a bit later and then see what I think about it.

Comment: its said that cicadas always have prime number of years in their hibernation cycles to prevent synching up with any predator population booms. http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/elements/2013/05/why-cicadas-love-prime-numbers.html

Comment: Ok, I am out. The answer from Filedunderwater is what you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The chaotic behaviour you are referring to (at least the one described in your link in the comments) is a property of the discrete version of the logistic equation, where you get chaotic dynamics at growth rates above ~3.55 (see [the logistic map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map)). The behaviour of this equation has been described in a classic paper by Robert May [(1976)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v261/n5560/abs/261459a0.html). As you increase growth rate (*a* in your link) from one you go from a stable attractor (approached directly or by dampened occilations) to cycling behaviour (between 2 to 4 to 8 states as growth rate increase) to chaotic dynamics, which is shown in this bifurcation diagram.

[image]

And to be clear, nothing of this has anything to do with period/cycle length per se (in the sense of species interactions or lagging feedback loops), but is a property of the model and the population growth rate. The statement about period 3 implying chaos probably refers to a brief window around r ~3.83 ($1+\sqrt{8})$ where you get cycling between three values, and at higher values then this you only find chaotic behaviour (which you get at lower values as well though).

**Addition:**
I now realize that the statement "*Period three implies chaos*" comes from the theoretical paper with the same name ([Li & Yorke, 1975](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~matilde/LiYorke.pdf)). This paper proves that all one-dimensional models (not only the equation above) that has a period 3 cycle will also show chaotic behaviour. This proof is a special case of the [Sharkovsky's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SharkovskysTheorem.html), which is older but was unknown to Li & Yorke at the time.

There is also a question at MathSE that deals with the same problem, and some of the answers there link to useful resourses:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2901/period-of-3-implies-chaos